# Lists of (x, y) coordinates into multiple lists of connected pixels

Tags: python, arrays, python-2.7, image-processing, python-imaging-library

I have a Python script that uses PIL and the HSV color space to detect all the red objects in an image.
[image: in action]

It can output a list of red pixels in the image that looks like `[(x,y),(x,y),(x,y),
   etc.]`

Using this list, I can find the center of all red pixels with `[sum(list(x))/len(list(x)) for x in zip(*list)]`

What I'd like to do is find the respective centers of all red objects (Both the center of the trash can AND the center of the folder). To do this, I want an efficient way to divide the list into multiple lists, one for each solid object. Then, I can take these lists and exclude the ones with fewer than 20 pixels to account for disconnected specks of color.

How can I best separate lists of (x, y) coordinates into multiple lists of connected pixels?

NOTE: I do not have `scipy`, `OpenCV`, or `scikit-image` available. I have `PIL` and `Numpy`

Comment: This sounds like an application for the union-find algorithm. Look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjoint-set_data_structure

Answer (score 1):

I ended up just using [breadth-first search](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search) to flood-fill the area. In this case, [depth-first search](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search) would've worked just as well, though.